# How to compare two polynomial and keep one of them

Tags: polynomials

I created a automatisation that assign different values to the coefficient of `Poly1 (a,b,c,d,e,f)`, this can be 0, eliminated some expression and in that moment I need to compare with the other polynomial if this expression can be removed, for example I have this:

```
Poly1:= a + by + cy^2 + dx + exy + fx^2 y^2
```

and I want to finish like this:

```
Poly2:= a + y + x + x^2 y^2
```

So, if assign `d=0`, x disappear and I dont want that.

I dont care the final coefficient values, only is important keep the order of structure.

i think to use function `Length`, like this:

```
IF[Length[Poly1] === 4, True, False]
```

Is a good idea, but I dont know what term I am going to get.

Other idea is compare the `Poly1` and `Poly2`.

```
If[Poly1 === Poly2,True,False]
```

But I need to eliminate the coefficients of `Poly1` only for compare and not using `===` because `Poly1` can have more terms that `Poly2`, while `Poly1` contains the terms of `Poly2`, `Poly1` is okay.

Comment: have a look at `CoefficientList`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You never voted! What a shame! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
poly1 = a + b y + c y^2 + d x + e x y + f x^2 y^2;
poly2 = a + y + x + x^2 y^2;
c[p_] := CoefficientList[p, {x, y}]
And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Equal, {c@poly1, c@poly2}, 2]

(* b == 1 && c == 0 && d == 1 && e == 0 && f == 1 *)
```